# Having trouble converting String to Double | SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, integer, double, converters

I've just started coding and I want to convert an Int variable to a Double variable.
But as I try with this code, it gives me the error:
`Cannot use instance member 'myInt' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalculatorWeb: View {
    
    var myInt = "325"
        var myDouble = Double(myInt)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(myDouble)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Text` expects `String`, so let's do a string

```
var body: some View {
    Text("\(myDouble)")  // << here !!
}
```

and make dependent property calculable

```
var myDouble: Double { // << here !!
  Double(myInt) 
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned String to Double so maybe Double(myInt) ?? 0

Answer (score 0):

Well, while the place between the `ContentView` and the body, your variables define it over there, that place is called **Init**. While running the **Init** process, your variables **cannot use each other**. But don’t feel sad, there’s a way to solve.

Code:

´´´

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalculatorWeb: View {

     var myInt = "325"
     @State var myDouble: Double = 0.0

     var body: some View {
          Text(String(myDouble))
          .onAppear{ myDouble = Double(myInt)! }
     }
}
```

´´´